# Program that test username and password in authorization required server?

Tags: c++, c, bots

I do: open start menu, run, nameofserver, then I get this: [image]

How to pass two strings (user name and password), put them on the form login and then simulate an enter press? If I grant login, stop to test, if not continue to put the strings and try to enter.

How can I do that through a program in C, C++ or C#?
Obviously is only academic, thanks in advance.

Comment: "Obviously is only academic" - OK. Then, show us what you have done so far. However, this questions seems to be way to broad.

Comment: If you would like to manipulate with win32 apps, you should read how to build them and how to communicate with them e.g. what PID do they run at, what is HWND/how to target current window/app needed and so on. It is a long way, you will have to spend at least few months :) I would not spend my time with win32 api :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

- enumerate the windows on the system
- find the one with the text "Windows Security"
- find it's children's HWND and search for the text fields
- SetWindowText (HWND, etc ... )
- Send a message to the "Ok" button

Tell us if it works or not ...